# can i compare using .equal() for two or more things in the same time

Tags: java, compare, equals, jgrasp

I should Define four boolean variables as follows:

- Freshman for students in levels 1 or 2.
- Sophomore for students in levels between 3 and 5.
- Junior for students in levels between 6 and 8.
- Senior for students in levels 9 or 10.

the user enters the course code, then I decide which level is the student (user) and then define the 4 boolean variables depending on the level.

But I don't know how to do the `equal()` for two thing or more.

this is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class point8 {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // declaring
        String CourseCode, Level;
        boolean Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, Senior;

        // input
        System.out.println("Course code:");
        CourseCode = input.next().toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("\nCourse Code: " + CourseCode);

        // output
        Level = CourseCode.substring(CourseCode.length() - 1);
        System.out.println("Student Level: " + Level);

        Freshman = Level.equals("1");
        System.out.println("Freshman: " + Freshman);

        Sophomore = Level.equals("3");
        System.out.println("Sophomore: " + Sophomore);

        Junior = Level.equals("6");
        System.out.println("Junior: " + Junior);

        Senior = Level.equals("9");
        System.out.println("Senior: " + Senior);

    }
}
```

What shall I do to compare from level 1 or 2 for freshman
and compare from level 3 to 5 for Sophomore ?

Comment: Put together all Level.equals() statements as single expression using braces () and ||

Comment: You should read the chapter about boolean expressions and conditions  in your programming introduction,

Comment: Also, consider using an `enum` instead of 4 booleans for your application. It may simplify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(Level.equals("9") || Level.equals("10"))
{
  //Senior
}
```

Update: The OR operator is something you should learn in the first couple weeks. The only thing more basic is to just write out the second if statement.

```
if(Level.equals("9"))
{
  //Senior
}
else if(Level.equals("10"))
{
 //Senior
}
```

Comment: but we didn't take this method in class yet. if i did it i'll lose a mark for using something that is not in the book

Comment: @Duha Ahh I see. Use Oceans answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you're better of using integers, just parse the `String` to `int`.

For example:

```
int myLevel = Integer.parseInt(Level);
if(myLevel >= 3 && myLevel <= 5)
{
  System.out.println("Sophomore: " + Sophomore);
}
```

You might get an error if the user inserts a letter instead of a number, to avoid this you need to catch the exception and handle it. This however is an entire different story, but you should readup about it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: i did exactly as you did but i get: variable Sophomore might not have been initialized

Comment: Ah yes, I just copied that from your post. You need to change that initialize it first or just replace it with `true`. (Didn't why you wanted to print that in the first place anyway.)